# How to parse json object properly?

Tags: php, loops, parsing, json

I'm trying to parse this JSON object and iterate through it to make a table in html. At the trials, I can't property echo the values. How do I do that correctly?

```
{"1":{"1":"Employer+EID","2":"File+Creation+Date","3":"File+Creation+Time","4":"Payer+EID","5":"Payer+QID","6":"Payer+Bank+Short+Name","7":"Payer+IBAN","8":"Salary+Year+and+Montd","9":"Total+Salaries","10":"Total+records","11":"","12":"","13":"","14":"","15":""},"2":{"1":"12435800","2":"20160714","3":"0318","4":"12435800","5":"","6":"DBQ","7":"QA79DOHB021104613880010010000","8":"201606","9":"183941.22166664","10":"113","11":"","12":"","13":"","14":"","15":""},"3":{"1":"Record+ID","2":"Employee+QID","3":"Employee+Visa+ID","4":"Employee+Name","5":"Employee+Bank+Short+Name","6":"Employee+Account","7":"Salary+Frequency","8":"Number+of+Working+Days","9":"Net+Salary","10":"Basic+Salary","11":"Extra+hours","12":"Extra+Income","13":"Deductions","14":"Payment+Type","15":"Notes/+Comments"},"4":{"1":"1","2":"27835620341","3":"","4":"SHIJAN+THARAKAN+THOMAS","5":"DBQ","6":"2025","7":"M","8":"30","9":"7300","10":"5000","11":"0.00","12":"2500.00000000","13":"200","14":"","15":""}}
```

I tried:

```
$data = json_decode($_POST['data'],true);

//echo count($data);

echo ($data[4][2]);`
```

The result was a `null` JSON. How can I do this correctly?

Comment: After you use `json_decode()`, use `print_r()` on the array to check the array data. What does it output?

Comment: echo `$data[4][2]` works to me and echoes 27835620341, perhaps `$post['data']` is undefined?

Comment: Works for me: [https://eval.in/605361](https://eval.in/605361)

Comment: the problem sits at $post['data']. Probably is empty. How you retrieve the json data?

Comment: @FirstOne, thanks its strange i get dif result. acutally i checked the network tab of my brower , the response was a null value set.

Comment: @dios231 , data is sent via ajax `$.ajax({    
    url:"print_f_wps.php",
    type:'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data:{data:fwpsData},
    async: false,
    success: function(dataX){ 
     
     
     
     }
            
   }); `

Comment: Quick note: some extensions such as `Postman` for chrome help a lot when testing stuff like that - You can change the request in a bunch of different ways with it.

Comment: try to **console.log** your data. in this case, fwpsData may be empty. Also, it's pointless to use ajax with "async: false;". Don't kill your browser :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON String is -

```
$str = '{"1":{"1":"Employer+EID","2":"File+Creation+Date","3":"File+Creation+Time","4":"Payer+EID","5":"Payer+QID","6":"Payer+Bank+Short+Name","7":"Payer+IBAN","8":"Salary+Year+and+Montd","9":"Total+Salaries","10":"Total+records","11":"","12":"","13":"","14":"","15":""},"2":{"1":"12435800","2":"20160714","3":"0318","4":"12435800","5":"","6":"DBQ","7":"QA79DOHB021104613880010010000","8":"201606","9":"183941.22166664","10":"113","11":"","12":"","13":"","14":"","15":""},"3":{"1":"Record+ID","2":"Employee+QID","3":"Employee+Visa+ID","4":"Employee+Name","5":"Employee+Bank+Short+Name","6":"Employee+Account","7":"Salary+Frequency","8":"Number+of+Working+Days","9":"Net+Salary","10":"Basic+Salary","11":"Extra+hours","12":"Extra+Income","13":"Deductions","14":"Payment+Type","15":"Notes/+Comments"},"4":{"1":"1","2":"27835620341","3":"","4":"SHIJAN+THARAKAN+THOMAS","5":"DBQ","6":"2025","7":"M","8":"30","9":"7300","10":"5000","11":"0.00","12":"2500.00000000","13":"200","14":"","15":""}}';

$result_array = json_decode($str, true);
echo '<pre>'; print_r($result_array);
echo $result_array[4][2];
```

It works fine for me. Please check you `$_POST['data']` variable. It may **undefined** debug this variable by `print_r($_POST);` if this **data** index is defined you will see an index of data such as -

```
Array
(
   ['data'] => 'some_value',
)
```